# Tracking on external forms.?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data, history-tracking, hidden-fields

I have a question regarding the tracking on external forms.

Here is the situation :

We send a satisfaction email to our client with some questions.

We have a data extension and for each field in the form, we have a column in the data extension

What we would like to do, is to be able to track the question results submitted from the forms
I mean, I would like each form field value to be pushed in marketing cloud

Could you please give me some information to do this?
I searched if there was an equivalent to silent post in Pardot, but in Marketing Cloud, but I found nothing

Could someone be so kind to give me some lead to follow

Comment: Can you share the pardot link to provide context?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use Smart Capture. Like in Pardot you can use hidden fields. See this screenshot from the help section of Marketing Cloud:

[image]

[Find an example of how to use this feature in Marketing Cloud Help Section here.](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/smart_capture_scenario_simple_form/)